# add a document which contains fields of type integers to firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

Whenever I add a new document to the database its fields by default take the type of string even when I add a number **(I'm using React.js)**

```
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
```

```
<input
     type="number"
     className="loginOrSignupPopup__age"
     placeholder="Age"
     value={age}
     onChange={(e) => {
         setAge(e.target.value);
         console.log(typeof e.target.value); // string
     }}
 />
```

```
async function createUser() {
    await addDoc(usersCollectionRef, { name: name, age: age });
    console.log(typeof age); // string
  }
```

This is how the field is saved in the firestore database
and I want it to be a number, not a string

[image]

Comment: Try `{name, age: +age}` in addDoc? Ideally you should use input if type number .

Comment: yes, it works I also find out that I can use Number() function {name: name, age: Number(age)}

Comment: Since you get this: `console.log(typeof e.target.value); // string` it really seems to be a string. You could try using `parseInt` to convert it to a number before passing it to the database.

Comment: @Steven ashraf make sure to use firebase security rule to validate the data type received

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this as Community wiki. As mentioned in the comments,

To save data as number in `firestore` database use `Number()` function.

Since you get this: console.log(typeof e.target.value); // string it really seems to be a string. You could try using parseInt to convert it to a number before passing it to the database.

You can also try `{name, age: +age}`